# Exception from setTimeout callback: { stack: [Getter] } and Mongo error

Tags: meteor, meteorite, node-fibers

I'm getting following exception thrown:

```
=> Meteor server restarted
I20130820-00:17:58.852(3)? Exception from setTimeout callback: { stack: [Getter] } MongoError: $or requires nonempty array
I20130820-00:17:58.852(3)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/alexei/.meteor/tools/4010e5731d/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
I20130820-00:17:58.853(3)?     at _.extend._nextObject (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:540)
I20130820-00:17:58.853(3)?     at _.extend.forEach (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:570)
I20130820-00:17:58.853(3)?     at _.extend.map (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:582)
I20130820-00:17:58.853(3)?     at _.extend.fetch (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:606)
I20130820-00:17:58.853(3)?     at _.each.Cursor.(anonymous function) [as fetch] (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:444)
I20130820-00:17:58.854(3)?     at MongoConnection.findOne (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:362)
I20130820-00:17:58.854(3)?     at _.extend.findOne (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:225)
I20130820-00:17:58.854(3)?     at _.extend.findOne (packages/collectionFS/collectionFS_common.js:4)
I20130820-00:17:58.855(3)?     at _.extend.checkQueue (packages/collectionFS/collectionFS_filehandlers.js:95)
I20130820-00:17:58.855(3)?     - - - - -
I20130820-00:17:58.855(3)?     at Object.toError (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
I20130820-00:17:58.855(3)?     at Cursor.nextObject.self.queryRun (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:634:54)
I20130820-00:17:58.856(3)?     at Cursor.close (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:903:5)
I20130820-00:17:58.856(3)?     at Cursor.nextObject.commandHandler (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:634:21)
I20130820-00:17:58.856(3)?     at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1658:9)
I20130820-00:17:58.856(3)?     at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:378:41)
I20130820-00:17:58.856(3)?     at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:468:18)
I20130820-00:17:58.857(3)?     at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
I20130820-00:17:58.857(3)?     at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/home/alexei/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:426:20)
I20130820-00:17:58.857(3)?     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
```

Please advise, what is causing the problem?

I'm on 0.6.5 meteor, 0.6.6 mrt, 0.10.13 node and 1.3.2 npm.

BTW, application itself works fine :)

Please advise.

Thank you,

Alexei

Comment: Looks like you have a $or mongo selector with an empty array. It seems to be located in the CollectionFS package. I looked at the code on GitHub (collectionFS_filehandlers.js, line 95) "$or: queryFilehandlersExists". 2 possibilities : either you're calling the API function with bad parameters, or the package code has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The query inside your `Meteor.setTimeout` block of code has an `$or` keyword which contains an empty array. You need to have at least two items in there for your operation.

If you're having trouble/using some kind of way to build an `$or` query you could update your code with this block of code so we could be of further help